Limit one purchase product category per year Woocommerce
I found this code in a previous post: Limit customers to buy a particular product multiple times within a certain time frame in WooCommerce and customized to limit the purchase of products per category (3 for regular and 1 for special promo) every year, but it doesn't work. Can anyone have a look and let me know where the problem is? TIA!
function action_woocommerce_checkout_process() {
    // Initialize
    $customer_email = '';
    
    // Get email
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // Get current user
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        
        // Get email
        $customer_email = $user->user_email;
    } elseif ( isset( $_POST['billing_email'] ) && ! empty ( $_POST['billing_email'] ) ) {
        $customer_email = $_POST['billing_email'];  
    } else {
        // Get billing_email
        $customer_email = WC()->customer->get_billing_email();
    }
    
    // NOT empty
    if ( ! empty ( $customer_email ) ) {      
        $time_in_years = 1;
        $limit = 1;
        $product_cat = 'regular'; 'special-promo';
       
        $orders_last_year_by_customer_email = wc_get_orders( array(
            'date_created'  => '>' . (time() - $time_in_years ),
            'customer'      => $customer_email,
        ));
        
        // Total (counter)
        $total = 0;
        
        // Iterating through each order
        foreach ( $orders_last_year_by_customer_email as $order ) {
            // Going through order items
            foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
                // Get product ID
                $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
                
                // Compare
                if ( $specific_product_id == $product_id ) {
                    // Get quantity
                    $quantity = $item->get_quantity();
                    
                    // Add to total
                    $total += $quantity;
                }
            }
        }

        // Show error when total >= limit
        if ( $total >= $limit ) {
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'Sorry, you can only purchase one time per year', 'woocommerce' ), $limit, $specific_product_id ), 'error' );
        }       
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_process', 10, 0 );


If you found the code in the previous post, why did you not ask the question on the post that was talking about this code?

There are many mistakes in your code… Also, you need to check cart items.
Try the following revised code version:
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'cart_items_validation' );
function cart_items_validation() {
    global $current_user;

    // 
    if ( $current_user->ID > 0 ) {
        $customer = $current_user->ID; // Get User ID
    } elseif ( isset($_POST['billing_email']) && ! empty ($_POST['billing_email']) ) {
        $customer = sanitize_email($_POST['billing_email']); // Get posted billing email
    } else {
        $customer = WC()->customer->get_billing_email(); // Get billing_email
    }

    if ( $customer ) {  
        $limit_by_term  = array( 'regular' => 3, 'special-promo' => 1 ); // Limit by defined category    
        $period_string  = '1 year'; // Time period string 
        $taxonomy       = 'product_cat'; // product category taxonomy
        $count_items    = array(); // Initialize
        
        // Loop through cart items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
            // Loop through category terms
            foreach ( array_keys($limit_by_term) as $category ) {
                // Count items for specific current category
                if ( has_term( $category, $taxonomy, $item['product_id'] ) ) {
                    if( isset($count_items[$category]) ) {
                        $count_items[$category] = $item['quantity']; // Add to count
                    } else {
                        $count_items[$category] += $item['quantity']; // Add to count
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Get customer orders 
        $orders = wc_get_orders( array(
            'status'        => wc_get_is_paid_statuses(),
            'limit'         => -1,
            'customer'      => $customer,
            'date_created'  => '>= ' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$period_string) ),
        ));
        
        // Loop through customer past orders (and loop through order items)
        foreach ( $orders as $order ) {
            foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
                // Loop through category terms
                foreach ( $count_items as $category => $count ) {
                    // Count items for specific current category
                    if ( has_term($category, $taxonomy, $item->get_product_id() ) ) {
                        $count_items[$category] += $item->get_quantity(); // Add to count
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Loop through categories (Initialize count by category)
        foreach ( $limit_by_term as $category => $limit ) {
            if ( isset($count_items[$category]) && $count_items[$category] > $limit ) {
                wc_add_notice( sprintf(
                    __( 'Sorry, you can only purchase %s %s per year from "%s" category', 'woocommerce' ),
                $limit, _n('item', 'items', intval($limit)), get_term_by('slug', $category, $taxonomy)->name ), 'error' );
            } 
        }
    }
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

I added the code and tested it. Nothing happens, I could add the products from the category and go to the checkout without any warning

Tried again with the editions and I was able to go through the purchase without any restriction

Tried again with the latest editions and it doesn't warn the user about the rules., it keeps the purchase process as usual. I tried it in a staging new site to see if there was a conflict between the plugins and it didn't work either

time() is a measure of SECONDS from the Unix Epoch
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php
In your code, you are subtracting 1 from the current time in seconds. Essentially looking back 1 second in time.
Wrong
'date_created'  => '>' . (time() - $time_in_years )

What you need to do is to use the Unix Time in seconds one year ago
Right
'date_created'  => '>' . (strtotime("-1 year") )

